# Can't inject service from my dynamic module into "registerAsync" of another module in NestJS

Tags: javascript, typescript, dependency-injection, nestjs

I created my own dynamic module to setup file upload for my project.

But when I try to inject service from my module in `registerAsync` method of MulterModule, I get this error:

```
Error: Nest can't resolve dependencies of the MULTER_MODULE_OPTIONS (?). Please make sure that the argument UploadsService at index [0] is available in the MulterModule context.

Potential solutions:
- If UploadsService is a provider, is it part of the current MulterModule?
- If UploadsService is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within MulterModule?
  @Module({
    imports: [ /* the Module containing UploadsService */ ]
  })
```

```js
        UploadsModule.forRoot({
            endpoint: process.env.S3_ENDPOINT,
            accessKey: process.env.S3_ACCESS_KEY,
            secretKey: process.env.S3_SECRET_KEY,
            bucket: 'testbucket',
        }),
        MulterModule.registerAsync({
            imports: [UploadsModule],
            inject: [UploadsService],
            useFactory: (uploadsService: UploadsService) => ({
                storage: uploadsService.getS3MulterStorage(),
            }),
        }),
```

I followed [this guide](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/dynamic-modules#module-configuration) from NestJS Docs and code of my UploadsModule is:

```js
import { DynamicModule, Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { UploadsService } from './uploads.service';
import { UploadsModuleOptions } from './uploads.types';

@Module({})
export class UploadsModule {
    static forRoot(options: UploadsModuleOptions): DynamicModule {
        return {
            module: UploadsModule,
            providers: [
                {
                    provide: 'UPLOADS_MODULE_OPTIONS',
                    useValue: options,
                },
                UploadsService,
            ],
            exports: [UploadsService],
        };
    }
}
```

And this is code of my UploadsService:

```js
@Injectable()
export class UploadsService {
    private readonly client: S3Client;
    private readonly bucket: string;
    private readonly multerStorage: StorageEngine;

    constructor(
        @Inject('UPLOADS_MODULE_OPTIONS')
        private readonly options: UploadsModuleOptions,
    ) {
        this.client = new S3Client({
            endpoint: options.endpoint,
            credentials: {
                accessKeyId: options.accessKey,
                secretAccessKey: options.secretKey,
            },
        });
        this.bucket = options.bucket;
        this.multerStorage = multerS3({
            s3: this.client,
            bucket: this.bucket,
            acl: 'private',
            metadata: (req, file, cb) => {
                cb(null, { fieldName: file.fieldname });
            },
            key: (req, file, cb) => {
                cb(null, file.originalname + '-' + Date.now());
            },
        });
    }

    getS3MulterStorage() {
        return this.multerStorage;
    }
}
```

UploadsModule exports UploadsService, `registerAsync` method of MulterModule imports my UploadsModule and therefore must be able to inject UploadService?

Answer (score 1):

Only your `UploadsModule.forRoot()` provides the `exports` of `UploadsService`, so when you use `imports: [UploadsModule]` you don't get the same providers exported. What I would suggest is create a separate module that does and import and export of the `UploadsModule` so you can import the wrapper and make use of [module re-exporting](https://docs.nestjs.com/modules#module-re-exporting)

```js
@Module({
  imports: [UploadsModule.forRootAsync(uploadModuleOptions)],
  exports: [UploadsModule]
})
export class WrapperUploadsModule {}
```

```js
MulterModule.registerAsync({
  imports: [WrapperUploadsModule],
   inject: [UploadsService],
   useFactory: (uploadsService: UploadsService) => ({
     storage: uploadsService.getS3MulterStorage(),
   }),
}),
```

Comment: I would export the `UploadsService` only instead of the module itself.

Comment: @ZimGil You can only export something that the module `imports` or providers (via the `providers` array), so you can't `exports: [UploadsService]` in the `WrapperUploadsModule` because it isn't in the `providers` array, you have to export the module instead

Comment: You’re right… 